# How do I search for email in Outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com

How do I search for email in my inbox with Outlook.com? In my Hotmail email account, I had a box where I could search for email in any folder. Where is that box situated now?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a search box in the top-left corner:

[image]

You can also focus on this box by pressing the <kbd>/</kbd> key. See [keyboard shortcuts for Outlook.com](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/outlook/keyboard-shortcuts).

Answer (score 0):

There is [a whole page on this](http://email.about.com/od/Outlook.com-Tips/qt/How-to-Search-Mail-in-Outlook-com.htm). The part that may be of most interest to you is:

> Click in the Search email field near your Outlook.com's top left corner.